# div to fill up the remaining space (width)

Tags: javascript, html, css

hey  there i have a div with 100% width (the width of computer screen can be anything) inside this width i have two child divs one with fixed width say 50px and i want the other child div to take up the remaining (100%-50px) space can anyone tell me how do i achieve this please ....

I have done like

```
<div style="width:100%;min-height:90px;">
<div style="float:left;width:50px;height:60px;">
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:90%;height:60px;">
</div>
</div>
```

in this code if 50 px is not the 10% of screen the there are some left blank space which I do not want

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXx3r/)

Only float the fixed width element.

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
}
.left {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that your left div is overlapping the right div if you do it this way. http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/vXx3r/1/

Comment: True, but you could easily set the left side of your right hand content to have either margin (if you use an inner div) or padding of 50px.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table layout:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-width"></div>
    <div class="fluid-width"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed-width {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
}

.fluid-width {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/zJq8N/

**OR...**

You could use `width: calc(100% - 50px)` which is [not supported in IE8 and below](http://caniuse.com/calc).

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed-width {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}

.fluid-width {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/mTq6x/

Comment: Wow I never knew about calc() +1